# Referencing a dynamic html in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, reference

Hello i just wanna ask about referencing dynamic html

heres my code

```
$('#firstselection').html(
'<br><br><br><br> <table border="1" ><tr><td><a id="test" href="#">Sea Shore</a> 
</td> </tr> ' +
'<tr><td><a href="#">Near the sea</a></td> </tr> ' +
'<tr><td><a href="#">Buildings near Sea</a></td> </tr> ' +
'</table>');
```

The code will be fired up when i hover an image but i did some researching about it but my code still doesnt work. I think im using the "on" wrong. anyone wanna clarify?

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
alert('clicked');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation as you are dealing with dynamic elements, the syntax of `on` for event delegation is slightly different

```
$('#firstselection').on('click', '#test', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

When you register an event handler it should always be bound to an element which is existing in the dom when the code is executed, in case of event delegation the target element filter can be passed as the second argument to `on()`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#firstselection').on('click','#test', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```